# Java programming help needed JButton

Tags: java, jbutton

```
button2 = new JButton ("Hello");
add(button2);
```

I want to change the `"Hello"` to an integer.

How must i change it?

Comment: You mean display text?

Comment: button2.setText(String.valueOf(100));

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 1;
button2 = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
add(button2);
```